# CSSTransition not working with React Portals

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, css-transitions, react-transition-group, react-portal

On this `StackBlitz`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/csstransition-test

I have a project that open a green div with a `zoom-in` effect:

**/src/App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';
import Modal from './Modal';

export default function App() {

  const [ isOpen, setIsOpen ] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>
      <br /><br />
      <Modal isOpen={isOpen}>
        <div>Hello World</div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**/src/Portal.js**

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const portal = document.getElementById('portal');

export default class Portal extends Component {
  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, portal);
  }
}
```

**/src/Modal.jsx**

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";
import Portal from "./Portal";

export default function Modal({ isOpen, children }) {

  const container = useRef(null);

  return (
    <CSSTransition
      nodeRef={container}
      in={isOpen}
      timeout={300}
      classNames="modal"
      unmountOnExit
      onEnter={ () => console.log('entered') }
      onExited={ () => console.log('exited') }
    >
      <div ref={container} style={{
        display: 'inline-block',
        backgroundColor: '#0f0',
        padding: '50px',
      }}>
        {children}
      </div>
    </CSSTransition>
  );
}
```

**/src/style.css**

```
h1,
p {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.modal-enter {
  transform: scale(0);
}
.modal-enter-active {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 300ms;
}
.modal-exit {
  transform: scale(1);
}
.modal-exit-active {
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 300ms;
}
```

**My problem is:** I need to make it work with Portals.

On file: **/src/Modal.jsx**, if I replace the `div` inside: `CSSTransition` with: `Portal` then I get errors.

This is the code with the change:

**/src/Modal.jsx**

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";
import Portal from "./Portal";

export default function Modal({ isOpen, children }) {

  const container = useRef(null);

  return (
    <CSSTransition
      nodeRef={container}
      in={isOpen}
      timeout={300}
      classNames="modal"
      unmountOnExit
      onEnter={ () => console.log('entered') }
      onExited={ () => console.log('exited') }
    >
      <Portal ref={container} style={{
        display: 'inline-block',
        backgroundColor: '#0f0',
        padding: '50px',
      }}>
        {children}
      </Portal>
    </CSSTransition>
  );
}
```

Please try the `StackBlitz`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/csstransition-test and you are also welcomed to post your own forked `StackBlitz` with the fixes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is happing because `CSSTransition` component is being created in `root` element. And the model is created in your `portal` element. This CSSTransition component is not wrapping anything.

You should instead wrap the whole Model with the portal, like this:

```
<Portal>
  <CSSTransition
    nodeRef={container}
    in={isOpen}
    timeout={300}
    classNames="modal"
    unmountOnExit
    onEnter={ () => console.log('entered') }
    onExited={ () => console.log('exited') }
    >
    <div ref={container} style={{
      display: 'inline-block',
      backgroundColor: '#0f0',
      padding: '50px',
    }}>
      {children}
    </div>
  </CSSTransition>
</Portal>
```

I hope this helps.